# Is there a way to force a website to be run in Fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, security, web

For context, it is an online examination website and I would like to know if the user can be prevented from leaving the webpage to prevent any cheating. I have read about using "secure browsers", but the aim is to build a website that can be run on any browser and platform. Any thoughts would be welcome.

Comment: For security reasons, no.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any way for a webpage to prevent a user from exiting it (that would be very bad for many security reasons). Even if it did, people could always use another computer to get around the problem, or just write down notes. In general it is extremely difficult to prevent cheating in online exams.